# How to explain from the second law that absolute zero cannot be attained?

Tags: thermodynamics, carnot-cycle

How can we explain from thermodynamics that the absolute zero of temperature cannot be attained?

I was thinking along the following lines. The efficiency of Carnot engine $\eta=1-\frac{Q_2}{Q_1}=1-\frac{T_2}{T_1}$ where $Q_1$ is the heat absorbed from the higher temperature reservoir at temperature $T_1$ and $Q_2$ is that rejected to the lower temperature reservoir having temperature $T_2$. Since $Q_2$ can never be zero by the second law of thermodynamics and as $T_1$ cannot be infinite, $T_2$ cannot be zero.

- Is this a valid explanation for why absolute zero cannot be attained? Is there any other way of explaining this from second law without talking about Carnot engine?